# Sqlite enabling in PHP 5

Tags: php, sqlite

I know similar questions have been posted but they don't answer my question as far as I can tell.

I have PHP 5.3 that is supposed to have sqlite3 extension installed

php.ini does NOT have sqlite3 extension like commented so it should work.

However it is not recognized as installed..

Answer (score 0):

is the actual sqlite extension in the extension directory?

Where this directory is will depend on what OS version you have and what setting is in your php.ini file.  You can verify this by using a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` page to see where it is pulling from.